# Tesseract on linux

Tags: linux, tesseract-ocr

How to solve the problem without having to install tesseract 3.03 when I get a warning:

> Warning: You are running an unsupported version of Tesseract.
>   Expecting version 3.03, your version is: 3.02.02 Error opening data
>   file /usr/local/share/tessdata/lus.traineddata Please make sure the
>   TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of
>   your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language 'lus' Tesseract
>   couldn't load any languages! Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if package is installed

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep tesseract
   ```
2. Install teseract [using packages](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki)

   ```
   sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
   ```
3. Search/install for available related packages

   ```
   apt search tesseract | grep -B1 language
   ```
4. Use a valid [ISO 639-2 (three letters) language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes).

   ```
   tesseract image.png -l spa myoutput
   ```

Will generate `myoutput.txt`

#### Related

- [Improve quality of image before OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality)
- [Add text to PDF](http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/) with `pdfsandwich  -verbose -lang spa -layout single scanned.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

Just copy the files from:  openalpr/runtime_data/ocr/tessdata     to    /usr/local/share/tessdata